# Validation triggered on create model with relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have in my application 2 models, `User` and `Notification`, like so:

```
class Notification < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  validates_presence_of :content, on: :create
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :notifications

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
end
```

Whenever I'm going to create a new notification I use the following code:

```
users = User.where(kind: params[:kinds])
unless user_ids.nil?
   users += User.where(id: user_ids)
end
@notification = Notification.create(content: notification[:content], user_ids: users.uniq)
```

This works fine but I'm seeing a lot of db checks on the logs. Is this normal? Is there anything I can do to lower the amount of db access?

Log snippet:

```
User Load (2.1ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."kind" IN ('parent', 'student', 'teacher')
  (0.1ms)  begin transaction
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = '[REDACTED]' AND "users"."id" != 34) LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = '[REDACTED]' AND "users"."id" != 36) LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = '[REDACTED]' AND "users"."id" != 38) LIMIT 1
User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE ("users"."email" = '[REDACTED]' AND "users"."id" != 40) LIMIT 1
...

SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications" ("content", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["content", "asdadasd"], ["created_at", "2016-03-05 13:18:27.285540"], ["updated_at", "2016-03-05 13:18:27.285540"]]

SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications_users" ("user_id", "notification_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 34], ["notification_id", 843]]
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications_users" ("user_id", "notification_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 36], ["notification_id", 843]]
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications_users" ("user_id", "notification_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 38], ["notification_id", 843]]
SQL (0.1ms)  INSERT INTO "notifications_users" ("user_id", "notification_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["user_id", 40], ["notification_id", 843]]
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that the first problem is you are loading all the users each time you want to send a new notification

i.e.this line:

```
users = User.where(kind: params[:kinds])
```

Then you add more users to this object, each lookup is resulting in a db call to determine if the user already exists.

You should rather retrieve all the user ids into a hash, then add to this hash if it doesn't. Next, send out your notifications based on these ids in this hash.

Comment: That does not work. Calling `Notification.create(content: '', users: User.all)` will still validate each user. That means each and every user will validate email uniqueness. The problem is not how I fetch the `User` model. Is how validation is being called